# from js array to php via stringify

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to correctly format some dynamic data from js (I will send it to php later on).

I need it with the following format:

```
{ "r" : "pax" , "c" : 1 , "w" : [ "kiwi" , "melon"] , "g" : [ "cat" , "dog"]}
```

And currently am using:

```
var send = [];
send.push ('r:pax');
send.push ('c:1');


var w = ["kiwi", "melon"];
send.push('"w":'+w);

var g = ["cat", "dog"];
send.push('"g":'+g);

s=JSON.stringify(send);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s;
```

Which returns:

```
["r:pax","c:1","\"w\":kiwi,melon","\"g\":cat,dog"]
```

I've seen that stringify is the solution, however I can't get to correctly pass keypairs correctly.

how can I do this?

Regards.

Comment: Use an object instead of an array: `var send = {}; send.r = 'pax'; send.g = ['cat', 'dog'];` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send shouldn't be an array, according to the format that you want your final output to be, but an object. Something like the following:

```
var send = {
    r: "pax",
    c: 1,
    w: ["kiwi", "melon"],
    g: ["cat", "dog"]
};

var s = JSON.stringify(send);
```

Answer (score 2):

mmm why are you starting with an array anyway? ... if I understood well this can be easily solved using:

```
var s = JSON.stringify({
    r: "pax", 
    c: 1,
    w: ["kiwi", "melon"],
    g: ["cat", "dog"]
});
```

Comment: Hello, the reason I needed to add as array is because data is dynamic, it might just be 2 elements as well as 100. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're building the JSON incorrect, by doing it small parts. Just build a **NORMAL** Javascript array/object pair, then encode the ENTIRE thing to json afterwards.

Because you're passing in `key:value` strings, json's stringify doesn't know/care that it already is json. It just sees a string and applies string encoding rules to it. Hence all the extra escapes you're seeing.

Try

```
send = [];
send.push({w:['kiwi', 'melon']})
send.push({g:['cat','dog']});
s = JSON.stringify(send);
```

instead.